# Contacts Sync problems: phone contacts not syncing to Google

Tags: contacts, sync, htc-sense

I had some problems syncing my GMail contacts onto my phone, so I:

- did "Clear Data" for the Contacts app
- re-imported all my Google contacts from a CSV file into the "Google" account on the phone.

It managed to sync contacts with GMail after that.

But new contacts that I've added to the phone since haven't synced to GMail — although contacts from GMail *will* sync to the phone. (And if I delete them on the phone, they don't get deleted on GMail.) I'm also getting "Sync is currently experiencing problems" messages.

The question is: How can I make it sync again?

And if I can't, how can I avoid deleting the newly-added contacts or creating duplicates?

(I'm using an HTC Desire Z with HTC Sense.)

Comment: http://www.droidforums.net/threads/when-does-google-sync-contacts.14278/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that when you add a contact, the contact type is set to GMail.  If it's set to **phone** then it will not sync to GMail and will stay solely on the device.

Contact Type is the first field on add new contact and is set to phone by default.

Comment: Nope, they're definitely set as Google contacts. Good thought though...

Answer (score 1):

When you have a HTC droid phone with Sense, it seems to be required to setup your HTC Sense account to be able to synchronize contacts between Google or Exchange and your cell phone. 
At least, that is a statement which is to be read when starting the Sense setup app on your HTC Phone.