# Change existing contacts from 'phone' to 'gmail'

Tags: contacts, sync, htc-desire, gmail

When the contact items (or several) are set to 'phone', how can they be changed to 'gmail' in order to sync?

In the post [Contacts Sync problems: phone contacts not syncing to Google](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12663/contacts-sync-problems-phone-contacts-not-syncing-to-google),
it says that contacts set to 'phone' will not sync. So, how can they be changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to export your phone contacts in to vcf format and then again import it into Google contacts.

Steps in Android 4.2:

- contacts -> settings > Import/Export -> Export to storage.
- contacts -> settings > Import/Export -> Import from storage. - This will ask you to select your Google account to save.

Edit/Delete or remove duplicates in http://contacts.google.com. Thats easy.